# Ошибка при сборке из за UILabel в CollectionView

Tags: xcode, swift, swift4

Я новичек в Swift помогите исправить эту ошибку :c

**Есть функция:**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ABCCell
    cell.backgroundColor = self.randomColor()
    cell.CategoryTitle.text = titles[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Ошибок xcode не выдает, но при сборке выдает ошибку

**Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' (0x1036d6a20) to 'Project.ABCCell'**

Если убрать as! ABBCell ну и конечно cell.CategoryTitle.text = titles[indexPath.row], то все работает идеально...

Читал много разных похожих тем, но там в основном не было регистрации класса...

```
self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

---

В итоге я пересобрал проект... и все вроде стало нормально... теперь я на другом завис) Пытаюсь передать при клике по collectioncell через segue значения, но без результатно, пишет reason: '-[UICollectionViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-hLg-LT-DtA" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UICollectionView.'

Comment: Вы пытаетесь зарегистрировать для UITableView стандартную UICollectionViewCell, а затем ее привести к своей ABCCell?

Comment: Что то типо того, только не для UITableView, а для UICollectionView, я понимаю что возможно в этом ошибка, но как сделать подругому? я нашел пример похожий, но там используется viewController с делигированием от Collection... Я попробую позже через этот пример сделать, но все равно интересно, можно ли как то именно через Collection View...

Comment: Ой, при наборе ошибся, Table вместо Collection написал. Как Вы моздаете свою ABCCell?

Comment: Если честно не понимаю, в каком смысле создаю... Есть ячейка. К ней привязан класс ABCCell который UICollectionViewCell... в нем я и объявляю 2 UILabel CategoryName(пока что не использую) и CategoryTitle (который попытался изменить как раз в collectionView)

Comment: Можете приложить проект где воспроизводится эта ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

скорее всего вы в своем класее не объявили :UICollectionViewCell

```js
class ABCCell: UICollectionViewCell {

}
```

Ваш класс должен наследоваться от UICollectionViewCell

Answer (score 0):

1. Какой идентификатор стоит reuseIdentifier ? Идентификатор такой же у ячейки?
2. ```
   class ABCCell: UICollectionViewCell {

       @IBOutlet weak var CategoryTitle: UILabel!

   }
   ```
3. Перепроверьте привязку IBOutlet в storyboard

Comment: Связки я перепроверял, но возможно что то упустил... тк я навичек еще смотрел другие проекты и из них какие то вытаскивал контроллеры, возможно где то не добавилось упоминание...